# Hiding a Textfield and its Label in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two textfields, one called label and one called link. I want that when an user hits control-(dash), he only gets the label textfield. However, when I try to hide the textfield, only the textfield disappears and the label of link stays around. I can't use JQuery, so I haven't seen a solution here, if I miss it let me know.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form id='linkEditDiv'>
  <table>
   <tr><th>Label:</th><td> <input type='text'  name='label'></td></tr>
   <tr><th>Link:</th><td> <input type='text' name='link'></td></tr> 
 </table>
</form>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
var key=[];
        document.onkeydown = checkKey;
            function checkKey(e) 
            {
                e = e || window.event;
                 key[e.keyCode] = e.type == 'keydown';
        if (key[17]&&key[189])//checks if the control key and the dash key was hit
                {   

                        key=[];
                        document.getElementById('linkEditDiv').style.display='block';//if the textfield was already invisible 
                        document.getElementsByName('link')[0].style.display='none';
```

Comment: In the JS you're getting the "linkEditDiv" by ID while you set it as the name in the HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Horrible code, but put the name in the tr and it will hide everything.

HTML

```
<tr name= 'link'><th>Link:</th><td> <input type='text'></td></tr>
```

JS

```
document.getElementsByName('link')[0].style.display='none'
```

Note: This example uses your code and is not how I would do it. jQuery is your friend.

Edit: Reverted back to first version if that's what you need, but I wouldn't put a name attribute in a tr tag, you're better off using ID.

Comment: Thanks, your first version with name='link' works! I can't use Jquery, otherwise I would